# Component or HTML-Element added dynamically in ngOnInit are added twice

Tags: angular

In the lifecycle `ngOnInit` I try to add an element to the page. So I use a `Renderer2`, create a new element and add it. The issue is simple. The item is created twice. Notice that I have a `console.log` in `ngOnInit` and I got only one log in the console. I must so assume that `ngOnInit` is not really executed twice.

I tried to reproduce the issue in a stackblitz, and I can't... Here is the code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r5psb2?file=src%2Fmain.ts

So I tried to reproduce the issue in an empty project with my IDE (vs code), and in that case, I have the issue. So my code is the same that the one in the stackblitz but the result is 2 `p` elements instead of 1.

Notice that if I look at the page source, I got only 1 p element while in the DOM, there are 2 of theme. Here is the page source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Issue</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body><!--nghm-->
  <app-root _nghost-ng-c1098833243="" ng-version="17.3.1" ngh="0" ng-server-context="ssr"><p _ngcontent-ng-c1098833243="">some text</p></app-root>
<script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

<script id="ng-state" type="application/json">{"__nghData__":[{}]}</script></body></html>
```

I assume that if the issue doesn't show up in stackblitz, it come from my settings. I tried to desable ssr but it doesn't do the trick (and even if it does, it seams bad).

Comment: What version of Angular do you use, and what is your ssr config?

Comment: @Shlang Angular 17.3.2 . For the ssr, I turned `build>options>prerender` (in angular.json) to false. I don't know if it's enough to disable ssr.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior with SSR and hydration enabled because your component's `ngOnInit` is called on the server side, where it generates the first `<p>` and then it is called on the client side where it generates the second `<p>`.

You can fix this behavior in a few ways:

1. Run the code only on one of the platforms

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: Object) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!isPlatformServer(this.platform)) { // <-- runs only on the client
      /* Code for inserting a node */
    }
  }
}
```

2. Disable hydration for the whole application by removing `provideClientHydration()` from `app.config.ts`.
3. Disable hydration for this particular component using `ngSkipHydration` attribute

```
@Component({
  /* ... */
  host: { ngSkipHydration: 'true' },
  /* ... */
})
```

*With hydration disabled the component still runs ngOnInit and adds a `<p>` element on the server, but on the client side the whole DOM is wiped before the application starts*

4. Disable SSR (disabling prerendering is not enough) by removing the following lines in architect > build > options section of `angular.json`:

```
"prerender": true,
"ssr": {
  "entry": "server.ts"
}
```

In this case, you may also need to clean up some ssr-related stuff, e.g. files with `server` suffix.

---

Please read the documentation regarding [SSR](https://angular.dev/guide/ssr) and [Hydration](https://angular.dev/guide/hydration#what-is-hydration) before making a choice.

Comment: Seams perfect ! I try with the solution `isPlatformServer`, make sure that everything works as expected and validate your answer after that. Thanks !